# Alert Dialog does not work for all items of the list

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a list view of places in which I get from a database, I made an OnItemLongClickListener on the items, after the long click an alert dialog is activated with some information, in the message body, which I get from the database concerning the item clicked. The dialog has 3 buttons (Call, Map it and View Photo) which are working fine. The dialog works for the first 8 items and then the dialog doesn't open and the application force closes for the rest of the items I don't know why!

Can you please help me?

Here is the code in which the list of all Hotels is displayed:

```
List<Hotel> values = datasource.getAllHotels();
            if (values.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No results found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i1 = new Intent(hotelSearchList.this, hotelSearch.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<Hotel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Hotel>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

And this is the code for the onItemLongClickListener:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String hotelName = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();
    final List<Hotel> location = datasource.getHotelLocation(hotelName);
    String loc = "Location: " + TextUtils.join(", ", location);
    List<Hotel> address = datasource.getHotelAddress(hotelName);
    String add = "Address: " + TextUtils.join(", ", address);
    List<Hotel> rating = datasource.getHotelRating(hotelName);
    String rat = "Rating: " + TextUtils.join(", ", rating);
    List<Hotel> phone = datasource.getHotelPhone(hotelName);
    final String phoneN = "Phone: " + TextUtils.join(", ", phone);
    List<Hotel> latitude = datasource.getHotelLat(hotelName);
    final String lat = latitude.get(0).toString();
    List<Hotel> longitude = datasource.getHotelLon(hotelName);
    final String lon = longitude.get(0).toString();
    List<Hotel> photo = datasource.getHotelPhoto(hotelName);
    final String pho = photo.get(0).toString();
    //Toast.makeText(hotelSearchList.this, "The hotel clicked is " + hotelName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Information About " + hotelName);
    builder.setMessage(loc + "\n" + add + "\n" + rat + "\n" + phoneN + "\n");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneN));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("View Photo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(hotelSearchList.this, imageV.class);
            i.putExtra("photo", pho);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Map it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(hotelSearchList.this, mapActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("latitude", lat);
            i.putExtra("longitude", lon);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.show();
    return false;
}
```

Here is the log cat:

```
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at egypt.interfaceAct.touristicASearchList.onItemLongClick(touristicASearchList.java:134)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:1753)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.widget.AbsListView.access$600(AbsListView.java:72)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:1711)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-28 19:47:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code and your logcat errors so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @MahaK It shows Null Pointer in Line 134 ..Check that line..What line it is???

Comment: public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position,
   long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String hotelName = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();

This one I guess

Comment: @MahaK Try to print Value at clicked position.. May be the clicked position value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent time to set some breakpoints in `onItemLongClick()` and use your debugger. It will help you find the null value or at least find the line where it crashes.

I'm willing to guess that the number of times the dialog opens is irrelevant, I assume your 8th entry that has a dud.  If you click the 8th entry first does it still crash?  If so, you check your database, does the row for the 8th `hotelName` have *all* of the fields that you request or does one (or more) columns have a *null* value?

**Addition**

When the list has scrolled and you use this line:

```
String hotelName = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();
```

The position is out of bounds which returns *null* causing your NullPointerException since the only children of parent are the visible ones, instead try a faster, simpler approach:

```
String hotelname = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

Comment: The problem is at this line:
String hotelName = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();

but I'm not sure why it works for the first items and not this one and I couldn't figure out while debugging!
And If I click the 8th item first it still crashes.

Comment: Excellent, by setting the breakpoint on that line have you verified: the value of `position` and that `parent` has a child at `position`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, when I debug and click on the 8th element in the list, the debugger stays on the same line even though I press the "Resume" button twice and then "ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() is opened in the prespective with "Source not found" written in it.

Comment: When you receive the "Zygote..." messages your code has already crashed. If the null pointer is at the `String hotelName = ...` line and you have a breakpoint set on that line, then when the debugger pauses (before you click resume) look in your "Variables" window.  You should see at least 'this', `parent`, `view`, `position`, and `id`; if you sift through `parent` you'll see that the only children listed at the _visible_ ones and you must off set `position` accordingly. **Solution** I just realized that you should use `view` instead, I'll edit my answer with some code in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

By first 8 times you probably mean the items displayed on the screen without needing to scroll, right?

You'd need to post some code in order for us to help you.

Comment: Yes I think this has to do with the items displayed! I will post some code now